# how to passing these data return into other pages react navigation page?

Tags: react-native, expo

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Expo from 'expo';

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component{
async signInWithGoogleAsync() {
    try {
      const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId: '768673945897-ftrhehlg3io4v2fohdbpacio1vghos8v.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        //iosClientId: YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE,
        scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
      });

      if (result.type === 'success') {
            console.log(result);
            //this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
            return result.accessToken;
            return result.user.name;
            return result.user.photoUrl;
      } else {
        return {cancelled: true};
      }
    } catch(e) {
      return {error: true};
    }
  }

render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <Button 
                onPress={this.signInWithGoogleAsync.bind(this)}
                title='Google Sign in'     
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: hello, i need help how to passing data array form "return result.user.name" into other pages let say in Profile Page, btw iam using react navigation..

thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to access data in some other component or page than you should use redux store. You can store the data obtained or generated in the current page to the redux store which will be accessible to any component or page which requires it.

Comment: there is no other way? if it really means I have to more learn redux ?

Comment: In react, the data stored in state is not accessible to other pages. Which is why you need a store which is global. That is provided by redux. You can get the data in any page with redux. Initially, I started working on a project with just react and later, came across the similar roadblock. Therefore, had to learn redux.

Comment: if you just need to send the data to some pages, you can use props.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing [parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) like this

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and retrieve the data like this...

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    /* 2. Get the param, provide a fallback value if not available */
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
    const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
        <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details... again"
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.push('Details', {
              itemId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            })}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
        <Button
          title="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. it solved already, thanks for helping :))
   btw i just passing this array data into navigator :)

> result = [object]
>
> this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { result: result.user });

2. and then in other pages let say Profile, i make contrsuctor for new state

> this.state = {
>         result: this.props.navigation.state.params.result, };

3. and then i call that state in each section like this

> { this.state.result.email }